# Jenkins Copy Artifacts from Upstream Job to Downstream and back

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, copy, jenkins-groovy, artifacts

I have Job A that call to another Job B

Job B know copy from Job A the artifact.

How I can do copy back of another artifact from Job B to Job A?

```
Job A
//////////

 stage('Validation'){
                'Binary Scan':{
                    build job: 'JOB_B'
                },    
           )
        }


Job B 
/////////

stage('Copy Artifacts from Job A'){

copyArtifacts filter: 'testz.zip', 
fingerprintArtifacts: true,
projectName: currentBuild.upstreamBuilds[0].fullProjectName,
selector: upstream()

}

stage('Do something'){
}


stage('Copy Artifacts back to Job A'){

/////?????????
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From within a project, you can't normally execute arbitrary code into a different project.

What you can do is for the Job B to use `archiveArtifacts`, and when it completes, the calling job (Job A) can retrieve the artifacts from the instance of Job B it triggered.
The `build` command will return a job 'handle' that has enough information to let you build a `copyArtifacts` command.

```
job A
//////////

stage('Produce artifacts'){
     // First, produce some artifacts for Job B and archive them so that they are available to Job B
     archiveArtifacts artifacts: "testz.zip"
}

stage('Validation'){
     // Invoke Job B (blocks until job B completes)
     def jobB = build job: "JOB_B"

     // Retrieve artifacts from Job B after it completes
     final String artifactsFilter = "build/*.csv"
     copyArtifacts filter: artifactsFilter, projectName: "JOB_B", selector: specific("${jobB.number}")
     // re-attach the same artifacts to Job A (now that they have been copied back into Job A workspace)
     archiveArtifacts artifacts: artifactsFilter
}


Job B 
/////////

stage('Copy Artifacts from Job A'){
    copyArtifacts filter: 'testz.zip', fingerprintArtifacts: true,
                projectName: currentBuild.upstreamBuilds[0].fullProjectName,
                selector: upstream()
}
stage('Do something'){
}
stage('Archive Artifacts for Job A'){
    // Archive desired artifacts
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: "build/**.csv"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay.  Can you explain more please. I not clearly understand it.  I want that the Job B will return artifacts to Job A, and when i try to parse all variables in Job B i cant find the Job A parameter that I could  add to copy artifacts.

Comment: That's because you need to do it the other way around. You can't push artifacts to job A from sub-job B. Instead, you need to archive Artifacts in job B, and when it completes and returns control to job A, job A will pull these artifacts using the job B handle returned by the build command. Updating the answer with some code

Comment: Is it possible to do an opposite operation - copy/publish TO upstream job instead of FROM ?

Comment: The example above shows you how to export artifacts to a downstream job B, from the upstream job B, and vice-versa